# How would I select this input using Javascript selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am not sure how to select the input below using Javascript selectors.  I tried this but that doesn't seem to be correct:

```
$("input:text[name=[11235]");
```

```
<div class="Row-LineDetail A" id="Row1235">
<span class="Col-Label LineIndent1">
</span>
<span class="Col-Dollar">

<input type="text" name="l1235" value="$5,000.00" cols="8"   onkeyup="validateNegAmount(this);" onblur="transform(this)" onfocus="removeFormatters(this);this.select();">

</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its jquery selector, you have to add jquery api to your page

Comment: FYI I am using JQuery and JQuery API is imported to my page.  FYI this is my first time posting to Stack Overflow, and the speed of responses here is incredible!  Thanks for the info!

Josh
Portland, OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
$("input[name='11235']");
```

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ for more information about attribute selectors.

Comment: The letter 'l' in the name was also throwing me off!  I thought it was the number '1'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="l1235"]')
```

That would work if you are using jQuery, as in your example above.

Comment: If you are NOT using jQuery, the answer is going to be a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using jQuery the following would work:

```
   $("input[name='l1235']")
```

Answer (score 0):

with using jquery 
`$('input[name="l1235"]')`

with pure javascript
`document.getElementsByName('l1235')`

Answer (score 0):

#### For you

Simply use

```
$('input[name=l1235]');
```

#### Other method

If you want to select the text elements, then you can ues

```
$('input[type=text]');
```

Other queries can be executed after this such as:

```
if($(this).attr('name') == 'l1235') {
```

And so on! :)